# How to edit the script so variable values will be contained within apostrophes without the need that the user will add apostrophes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I wrote the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT="5"
SESSIONS="8"

function usage {
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) -l servers.list -c COMMAND"
    echo ""
    echo "Options:"
    echo "   -l               :     Provide list containing hostnames/ips"
    echo "   -c               :     Command to run"
    echo "   -u [optional]    :     Run commands remotely as supplied user"
    echo "   -r [optional]    :     Connect to remote machine as root, run commands as supplied user"
    echo ""
    echo " **** \"-u\" is mandatory if \"-r\" is used ****"
    echo ""
}

while getopts ":l:c:u:r:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        l)
            LIST=$OPTARG
        ;;
        c)
            COMMANDS="$OPTARG"
        ;;
        u)
            USER=$OPTARG
            USERSWITCH="-l $USER"
        ;;
        r)
            RUSER=$OPTARG
            RUSERSWITCH="-l root"
            RUSERCMD="su - $USER -c '$COMMANDS'"
        ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $LIST ]] || [[ -z $COMMANDS ]]; then
    echo "Error - not enough arguments have been supplied"
fi

if [[ -z $USER ]]; then
    /usr/bin/pssh -i -p $SESSIONS -t 100000000 -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" -O ConnectTimeout=$TIMEOUT -h $LIST "$COMMANDS"
    echo "user not supplied"
elif [[ ! -z $USER ]] && [[ ! -z $RUSER ]]; then
    echo "connecting as root running as user"
    /usr/bin/pssh $RUSERSWITCH -i -p $SESSIONS -t 100000000 -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" -O ConnectTimeout=$TIMEOUT -h $LIST "$RUSERCMD"
elif [[ ! -z $USER ]] && [[ -z $RUSER ]]; then
    echo "Connecting as supplied user"
    /usr/bin/pssh $USERSWITCH -i -p $SESSIONS -t 100000000 -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" -O ConnectTimeout=$TIMEOUT -h $LIST "$COMMANDS"
fi
```

It basically wraps the command "parallel-ssh" and allows some more functionality which is required at my workplace, such as supplying a list or running commands as a specific user.

The script works perfectly.

The only issue I have is with the command supplied after the "-c" switch - it must be put inside ("") or the spaces in the command will cause the variable to get only the first word in the command.

How shall I edit the script so it would be able to get whatever is after the -c even if not put in ("")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this (thanks @JohnKugelman for the useful tips):

```
c)
    shift "$((OPTIND-2))"
    cmd=$(printf "%q " "$@")
    break
```

- `OPTIND`: the index of the next argument to be processed
- `$((OPTIND-2))`: the number of arguments up to the `-c` option
- `shift "$((OPTIND-2))"`: shifts away everything up to the `-c` option
- `printf "%q " "$@"`: prints the remaining arguments (`$@` - only the command because everything else has been shifted away)
- `%q`: `help printf -> quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for updating. Personally I'd still use `cmd=("$@")` and delay the `printf %q` step until as late as possible. I prefer to use the best internal representation for values possible (i.e. commands in arrays) and delay their conversion into other formats as late as possible. That's a point of style, though, not correctness. Your answer is now nice and safe.

Comment: Why is the “break” needed? Because of the “shift”?

Comment: The `break` forces an exit of the loop around `getopts`. Since multiple args are being concatenated after the `-c`, that option is necessarily the last one. `break` here ensures that anything on the line will not be parsed by `getopts`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you are facing this problem but using variables as `${COMMANDS}` is always a good practice as it keeps all the variables intact.

Since you are using a variable after `-c` you should go with `RUSERCMD="su - $USER -c '${COMMANDS}'"`